# I would like to know how to calculate the percentage of a color in an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to know how to calculate the percentage of a color in an image, the image below represents 100%:
[image: 100%]
already this, when the level decreases:
[image: decreases]
I wanted to learn correctly how do I get the percentage that the bar has at the moment, I tried to use the Matplotlib library, but I could not get the expected result, could anyone help me please? I do not need something ready, someone to teach me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proposition:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from urllib.request import urlopen

full =  np.asarray(Image.open(urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnxX3.png")))
probe =  np.asarray(Image.open(urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx5zt.png")))

# crop the images to the same shape 
# (this step should be avoided, best compare equal shaped arrays)
full = full[:,1:probe.shape[1]+1,:]

def get_percentage(full, probe, threshold):
    def profile_red(im):
        pr = im[:,:,0] - im[:,:,1]
        return pr[pr.shape[0]//2]

    def zero(arr):
        z = np.argwhere(np.abs(np.diff(np.sign(arr))).astype(bool))
        if len(z):
            return z[0,0]
        else:
            return len(arr)

    full_red = profile_red(full)
    probe_red = profile_red(probe)
    mask = full_red > threshold
    diff = full_red[mask] - probe_red[mask]

    x0 = zero(diff - threshold) 
    percentage = x0 / diff.size * 100
    err = 2./diff.size * 100
    return percentage, err


print("{:.1f} p\m {:.1f} %".format(*get_percentage(full, probe, 75.0)))
```

Result:

```
94.6 p\m 2.2 %
```

Comment: if I put a local path to the images, it gives the following error:
print(Healing.get_percentage('C:/Users/Link/PycharmProjects/DBot/Imagens/Healing/Full_Settings/health.png','C:/Users/Link/PycharmProjects/DBot/Imagens/Healing/Real_Time/health.png',0.5))
full_red = profile_red(full)
pr = im[:,:,0] - im[:,:,0-1]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Yes because my code actually opens the image and converts it to a numpy array, while yours tries to manipulate the string of the path to the image, not the image itself.

Comment: full = np.asarray(Image.open("C:/Users/Link/PycharmProjects/DBot/Imagens/Healing/Full_Settings/health.png"))
probe = np.asarray(Image.open("C:/Users/Link/PycharmProjects/DBot/Imagens/Healing/Real_Time/health.png"))
threshold = 0.5
result = Healing.get_percentage(full,probe,threshold)
print(result)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Link\PycharmProjects\DBot\moduloHealing.py", line 103, in <module>
    result = Healing.get_percentage(full,probe,threshold)
  File "C:\Users\Link\PycharmProjects\DBot\moduloSettings.py", line 23, in get_percentage
    diff = full_red[mask] - probe_red[mask]
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 94 but corresponding boolean dimension is 93

Comment: I forgot to account for the possibility that the two arrays are identical. I updated the answer.

Comment: The updated a problem is related to my comment to best use identically shaped arrays as input. If you have identical shaped arrays, that step would need to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to calculate the progress by looking at the image
I'm not sure if there's a library to this specific thing but here's my simple approach to it,

you can compare images to get until which column they are similar and then can calculate the % task done, let me demonstrate..

```
!wget https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnxX3.png
a = plt.imread( './jnxX3.png')
plt.imshow( a )
```

[image: image with 100% progress]

This shall load the image with 100% completion in variable a

```
c =a 
c = c[: , 0:c.shape[1] - 50]
aa = np.zeros( dtype= float , shape=( 11,50,  3 ))
c = np.append( c, aa , axis= 1 )
plt.imshow( c)
plt.imshow( c )
```

made a sample incomplete image which you should have provided 
[image: with 47% progress]

```
def status( complete_img , part_image): 
    """inputs must be numpy arrays """ 

    complete_img = complete_img[:, 1: ] # as the first pixel column doesn't belong to % completion 
    part_image = part_image[:, 1:]

    counter = 0
    while(counter < part_image.shape[1] and counter < complete_img.shape[1]):         
        if (complete_img[:, counter ] == part_image[:,counter]).all():
            counter += 1 
        else :
            break
    perc = 100*( float(counter) / complete_img.shape[1])
    return 
status( a ,c ) # this will return % columns similar in the two images
```

Comment: unfortunately I could not use your method, could you explain a little more how to use the same?

Comment: are you getting any errors or you want me to elaborate

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageColor.html) library. There are two ways to measure color, Hue, Saturation, Luminance (HSL), and Red, Blue, Green (RGB). There are functionsto do both in the library.